# My MacBook Pro freezes if nothing is moving on the screen

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, performance

My MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Late 2013) started freezing every time I boot it.

I've tried resetting the NVRAM and SMC, and have even reformatted it.

After doing that, I noticed that if I kept moving the mouse (trackpad or external mouse), my computer would no longer freeze. However, if I stopped moving the mouse, then the computer would freeze again.

The computer doesn't have this behavior if I start it in Safe Mode.

**How might I troubleshoot this further?**

**Edit:** When I was trying to copy the log from Console, I had to move the cursor or the computer would freeze. But after I open Safari, I could stop with no issue. I shift tabbed on Console and then the Mac froze again!

**Edit 2:** After some test, I figured out new strange behaviors. If something is moving on my screen, no freeze.

I was on Youtube, and I played a video > no freeze during the entire video. I stopped the video > freeze after 2s.

I tried something else: I launched another video then I minimized the window > freeze after 2s, but I could still hear the sound.

It's like the computer's freezing only if nothing is moving on the screen.

Comment: Open console in Utility Folder, then monitor it, then stop moving (but remember the time down to a second) the muse, and see what it reports, copy the lines from the moment you stopped and the following 50 lines, then report here

Comment: I tried that already. There is absolutely nothing at the time it freezes. I guess even the logs are not saved?

Comment: I can not know what you tried ! As for the logs, the system logs everything just need to know how to look for it. Freezing is a big event. But since you do not want to post the log, I can not help you.

Comment: It's not that I don't want. But look, there is nothing. The mac freezes at 3:35:0ish. http://pastebin.com/Z1VVgqqa

Comment: If this is still an issue after reinstalling MacOS you might have a hardware problem.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking but those issues make no sense. See my edit, really strange!

Comment: how can it be hardware problem if it works in Safe mode ?

Comment: If it works in Safe mode it means one of your Apps is doing it. `Sep 26 03:35:00 Ashleys-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[379]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper  ` then it Reboots . 
`Sep 26 03:36:13 localhost bootlog[0]: BOOT_TIME 1537947373 0`

Comment: I just reinstalled the whole thing (it was High Sierra) and yesterday I installed Mojave. I didn't install any application. That's why I'm still thinking it could be hardware.

Comment: I edited my original post to add some informations.

Comment: If you run into similar issues with different freshly installed versions of maxOS it probably is hardware, not software.